# Get list from Single<List> observable

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I have a method which returns `Single<List<HistoryItem>>`. Now  I want to get list from this.

```
private fun getListOfDownload(): ArrayList<HistoryItem> {
    val downloads = manager.lastHundredVisitedHistoryItems()
    downloads.subscribe { t ->
        return t; // not allowed
    }
}
```

I could use `subscribe`  but that does not allow me to return list from that.

I tried `map` also.

```
downloads.map { t: List<HistoryItem> -> return t } // again `return t` is not allowed.
```

**Edit**

I could make this work by following

```
private fun getListOfDownload(): ArrayList<HistoryItem> {
        var list = ArrayList<HistoryItem>()
        val downloads = manager.lastHundredVisitedHistoryItems()
        downloads.subscribe { t ->
            list = t as ArrayList<HistoryItem>
        }
        return list
    }
```

Please tell

- If this way is right & will it not block main thread?
- Is there not a way to return the list without declaring another
  list?

I am new to Reactive programming so please explain me.

Comment: @AxelH I added java tag after edit, I think java developer can tell this. Because I am a java developer, and RX java is popular among java devs.

Comment: I don't think `private fun getListOfDownload(): ArrayList<HistoryItem>` is part of this library... EDIT: Ok, you are using kotlin... I am out ;)

Comment: @AxelH The purpose of this question is just how to get List from that observable. Doesn't matter the dev is Java/Kotlin/Android dev. By the way I have removed Java tag.

Comment: PS: if the rules are close to java stream, you need curly bracket with a return statement -> `t -> { return t; }` or `t -> t`

Comment: In RxJava, you should keep composing operators onto sources and finally subscribe to the final stage. Getting an item out needs blocking and will likely make your UI hang. How do you plan to use that list anyway? Recommended reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#simple-background-computation

Comment: It's kotlin, you don't need `return` keyword

Comment: @AxelH Thanks for your time, but `{return t;}` does not work. and the other syntax I did not get to use in my method.

Comment: @akarnokd I think you should provide a fast solution. As I am very new to Rx programming. Yes there are many tutorials. I put a question because I had not much time to get familiar with Rx programming.

Comment: @asm0dey As I said I am new to Rx, so can you just edit my method to make this work.

Comment: @Khemraj no, but what happens when you just delete 'return' word?

Comment: @asm0dey It says `A 'return' expression required in a function with a block body`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `getListOfDownload` is returning the `ArrayList<HistoryItem>`, while `lastHundredVisitedHistoryItems` of `manager` returning `Single<ArrayList<HistoryItem>>` which means the you want to observe `ArrayList<HistoryItem>`, becuase `lastHundredVisitedHistoryItems` gonna take some times.

that's why you can not return the item in subscribe block because that block is lamda which is going to observe `ArrayList<HistoryItem>` item.

But if you don't care about the observation you can do something like this,

```
private fun getListOfDownload(): ArrayList<HistoryItem> {
    val downloads = manager.lastHundredVisitedHistoryItems()
    return downloads.blockingGet()
}
```

**But you are loosing the asynchronus call of `lastHundredVisitedHistoryItems` as we are applying `blockingGet()`**, but as you are not observing it on seperate thread i am assuming that you want to call it on main thread.

But if you want to observe `lastHundredVisitedHistoryItems()` then you can pass the method as a parameter which will act as cosumer for `ArrayList<HistoryItem>`.

```
private fun getListOfDownload( listener : (ArrayList<LoginViewModel.HistoryItem>) -> Unit) {
        val downloads = manager.lastHundredVisitedHistoryItems()
        downloads.subscribe { t -> listener.invoke(t) }
}

// when you call above method look like below
// here variable `it` is nothing but a object of ArrayList<LoginViewModel.HistoryItem>
getListOfDownload { adapter.updateDataSet(it) }
```

Comment: Will this wait for fetching items?

Comment: Yes.. It going to block the thread from which thread you call it.

Comment: I am updating answer if you want to observe and want to perform task on background

Comment: @Khemraj check the edited answer, and yep parameter of subscribe is nothing but an interface, becuase of kotlin lambda we are doing in short way, if you have ever try it on java you have to use interface implementation.

Comment: I think I found shorter way without creating a new interface, please check my edited question, and let me know if that can be a solution.

Comment: @Khemraj  edited method is going to return an emptyList at time of call, becuase `lastHundredVisitedHistoryItems` gonna take sometimes, so until rxCall back will be there you are returning emptyList,

Comment: I have tested it, I am having 1 item in database, and its returning 1 item. Okay will it fail for many items?

Comment: @Khemraj that is most probably becuase you having only 1 item, do one thing add timer in your `lastHundredVisitedHistoryItems` then you will notice the behaviour.

Comment: @Khemraj try `delay` operator.
`downloads.delay(5000).subscribe { ... }` this means it will take 5 second to complete the execution.

Comment: Thanks for your time @Moinkhan. I have to accept Mark answer because that is more relevant to my need. I have upvoted your answer for the great explanation.

Comment: Okay I try this.

Comment: Yes, you are right. after setting delay the list is forever empty.

Comment: @Khemraj and in question nowhere you have specified that you want to do this `adapter.updateDataSet(downloadedList)`, if this is what you want then you can do it directly on subscribe block.

Comment: Yes, but I always do seperate code. that's why asked. like `getListFromDatabse()` function will not set items in list. It will only return list. That can be used from anywhere. No worries, I am updating adapter directly in subscribe now for solution.

Comment: @Khemraj my updated answer which is function as a parameter (my second solution) will work for you.
you can do like this at caller `getListOfDownload { adapter.updateDataSet(it) }`.
Which is more relevant because caller will decide what to do with data. Anyway i am considering that you solved your problem which is more important.

Comment: Hey @Moinkhan, I am wondered, it is working well. I thought I have to create a interface like java. and have to create invoke method. So I found that lengthy. But when I tested this, it does not require to make interface. That is great. Can you please explain about invoke a bit more? and what is Unit in this case? You deserve this mark right.

Comment: If I could upvote for 10 times, I would do. It is very useful info for me, it will help me removing unnecessary interface in kotlin.

Comment: In kotlin Unit is like Void of Java. And in our example we are passing function as parameter in listener object, so to call that method there is a method `invoke` which will call the method that we have passed in function parameter.

for more detail,
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html and read the Function Type section.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the subscribe lambda is `crossinline` meaning it does not allow local returns

What you would normally do here is use the list for its purpose (update recyclerView) in the `subscribe{}`

e.g.

```
val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

private fun downloadList() {
    manager.lastHundredVisitedHistoryItems()
        downloads.subscribe { downloadedList ->
            this.list = downloadedList
            // or
            adapter.updateDataSet(downloadedList)
        }.addTo(compositeDisposeable)
    }
}
```

you also need to add you disposable to a `CompositeDisposable` to prevent the possibility of a memory leek

Comment: What mean `CompositeDisposable`, will it clean the downloads item automatically after use.

Comment: what you do is call compositeDisposable.clear() in onDestroyView() this means if you have any long running network calls that live longer than the fragment, you don't hold a reference to the fragment

Comment: You reverted edit, did you notice you have unknown variable `l`? Also you did not declared `list`? in your example?

Answer (score 0):

You can get list using subscribe as follow:

```
 @NonNull
public Single<String> getHistoryPage() {
    return Single.create(new SingleAction<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(@NonNull final SingleSubscriber<String> subscriber) {


            mHistoryModel.lastHundredVisitedHistoryItems()
                    .subscribe(new SingleOnSubscribe<List<HistoryItem>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItem(@Nullable List<HistoryItem> item) {
                      final StringBuilder historyBuilder = new StringBuilder(HEADING_1 + mTitle + HEADING_2);      

                            Iterator<HistoryItem> it = item.iterator();
                            HistoryItem helper;
                            while (it.hasNext()) {
                                helper = it.next();
                                historyBuilder.append(PART1);
                                historyBuilder.append(helper.getUrl());
                                historyBuilder.append(PART2);
                                historyBuilder.append(helper.getTitle());
                                historyBuilder.append(PART3);
                                String url = helper.getUrl();
                                try {
                                    URL url1 = new URL(url);
                                    authority = url1.getAuthority();
                                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                historyBuilder.append(authority);   //No need of path showing of History file.
                                historyBuilder.append(PART4);
                            }

                            historyBuilder.append(END);
                            File historyWebPage = getHistoryPageFile(mApp);
                            FileWriter historyWriter = null;
                            try {
                                //noinspection IOResourceOpenedButNotSafelyClosed
                                historyWriter = new FileWriter(historyWebPage, false);
                                historyWriter.write(historyBuilder.toString());
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to write history page to disk", e);
                            } finally {
                                Utils.close(historyWriter);
                            }

                            subscriber.onItem(Constants.FILE + historyWebPage);
                            subscriber.onComplete();
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
}
```

By using above code u get history list in html page. You have to use StringBuilder for that and then you get your complete history page